# How to Open Activity even when app is in background when receive firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to open a call receiving to pickup or decline call on firebase notification receive. But it open activity when app is in foreground but when app is in background notification logs shows but never call activity.

public class FirebaseNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

```
private static final String TAG = "Firebase";
private int remedyNotificationID = 0;
NotificationManager notificationManagerRemedy;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Notification Received ");
    Map<String, String> data = null;
    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Notification Received: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        data = remoteMessage.getData();
    }
    if (data != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingVideoCallActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("user_id", data.get("user_id"));
        bundle.putString("user_full_name", data.get("user_full_name"));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: use click action to handle it in background scenario

Comment: i Did't understand. Can u please explain

Answer (score 0):

> There are two types of messages data messages and notification
> messages. Data messages are handled
> here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
> traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
> is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
> When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
> and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
> messages.

**Example code** :-
You need to specify click_action in your notification payload like this

```
$noti = array
    (
    'icon' => 'new',
    'title' => 'title',
    'body' => 'new msg',
    'click_action' => 'open IncomingVideoCallActivity'
);
```

Now in `manifest` file do this in your `IncomingVideoCallActivity` activity tag

```
         <activity
               android:name=".IncomingVideoCallActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="open IncomingVideoCallActivity" /> // should be same as in click action
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```